# Style of the Button in SWT/JFace

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

How do I change the style of a button in a JFace/SWT window, including font, colour and shape?

Answer (score 3):

All SWT elements have corresponding styling methods like:

```
setBackground(...)
setBackgroundImage(...)
setFont(...)
```

and so on.

In Eclipse before Juno it is the way you "style" widgets.

In Eclipse 4.0 it is possible to style with CSS. You can read more about this on [Lars Vogel's page about Eclipse 4 CSS Styles](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html).

Comment: above mentioned functions are only for formatting the existing the widget what if i have to create my own styled widget? e.g; if i want to create a button in circular shape then what should i do . I have to modify widgets for eclipse 3.4 only so i cant use CSS

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create/style a completely custom `Widget`, then you will have to create it yourself by subclassing `Canvas` or `Composite`.

There is an excellent tutorial from Eclipse here: [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm)

If you are just looking for ways to modify the color of existing `Widget`s, look at the answer from @MichalBorek.